# Where to store files for my Android App, Storage and Performance-wise

Tags: android, storage

I am building an android app which requires to have >300 images and ca. 100 audio files for an apk size of around 50mb (after webp compression and proguard).

It is not huge and I could probably live with that. But since I am planning to add other features the size will get bigger and bigger.

I am still interested though, since I'm quite new to android development, if there is a better way to store all this files, perhaps remotely and access them when required.

When the app starts I would have to load all the images into a list and once an element of the list is tapped I would need to open a separate activity and load the sound. So there is no upload from the App, just a resource gathering.

I do not know if it is more efficient this way or to store all the files locally.

**Either way I would like to know what my options are. what are the pros and cons of a server (and if it would be a viable solution for me at all) and what is the advantage of storing them locally instead.**

Please keep in mind that I working by myself and haven't got money to invest on premium servers or stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FILE STORAGE** will be best for you. Performance depends on the type and amount of data you are using. You do not need too much of data manipulation so go for file storage if privacy is not your concern for the data as it will be available for all the applications.

- Use **SQLite Database** if the files needs to be protected from other applications.
- Use **File Storage**(internal/external memory) if other applications can also access your files.
- Avoid Fetching data from server using **JSON parsing/Http requests** it will make your app rely on the internet all the time. Unless you are using it to update your database or file storage.